# Kotlin - Should I Introduce Null?

Tags: function, kotlin, null, return, match

What is the best practice to avoid returning null in the below situation? I feel like introducing null in Kotlin is a smell, but is it in this circumstance? Is there a better alternative?

```
fun getMatch(s1: String, s2: String) : Match? {
    MatcherType.values().forEach(){
        Matcher matcher = getMatcher(it)
        Match match = matcher.match(s1, s2)
        if(match != null){
          return match
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: This question seems to be more suitable for codereview than StackOverflow. But even before answering the null question, there are several things to consider here. Your code seems to be half Java. What is `Matcher`? Why do you create a new empty instance of it every time? Why does iterating on a `Matcher`'s values require you to call `getMatcher(it)` on each of them? Aren't those values matcher instances already? Also you return at the first loop iteration every time here, so you'll never search for other matchers.

Comment: Now null in itself is really not a problem, Kotlin will protect you from misuses of null (unlike Java). So the answer depends on how you want to represent the absence of match. And null seems like a good fit for it.

Comment: @Joffrey
"So the answer depends on how you want to represent the absence of match" Exactly, I mean I could use optional, I could use an exception, I could use some kind of status flag in the match object, but in the end using plain old null seems to make the most sense because kotlin supports null safety.

Comment: The standard library uses `null` all over the place to represent "nothing found". It's perfectly appropriate. In fact, you can use one of those standard functions to simplify your above function to `= MatcherType.values().firstOrNull { getMatcher(it).match(s1, s2) }`

Comment: Actually, my example needs to be `= MatcherType.values().firstOrNull { getMatcher(it).match(s1, s2) != null }`